# Is the finite set of all partial functions in $\mathbb{N}$, $f:(0,n)\rightarrow (0,n)$, computable?

Tags: functions, logic, recursion, computability

I have developed the next conjecture:

> **CONJECTURE: The set of all partial functions in $\mathbb{N}$, $f:(0,n)\rightarrow (0,n)$, being n a finite natural number, is a set of computable functions, and the cardinality of this set is $n^n$ (finite).**

I think that there are no NON-computable functions in $\mathbb{N}$, $f:(0,n)\rightarrow (0,n)$, because this set is finite. Could you please tell me if this is correct?

Comment: Well do you intend the domain/range of your functions to be $\mathbb{N}$ or $\{1,2,3,.....,n-1\}$? If it's the latter, then yes, the number of such functions will be finite.

Comment: The domain/range of functions is {0,1,2,3,..., n-1}. Yes, the set is finite, but could be a function in this set that not be computable?

Comment: Uncomputability is a possibility only when the domain can be infinite.

Comment: The title doesn't match the question body. The title asks if the set of all partial function $n \to n$ is computable, while the body asks if each of the functions is itself computable.  Every function $\mathbb{N} \to \mathbb{N}$ with a finite domain is computable, because we can just list the values in a table and use that to perform the computation.  On the other hand, it is possible to have a finite set of function $\mathbb{N}$ to $\mathbb{N}$ so that each of the functions is computable but the *set* is not itself computable.

Comment: @CarlMummert " it is possible to have a finite set of function $\mathbb{N}$ to $\mathbb{N}$ so that each of the functions is computable but the set is not itself computable." Sorry, what do you mean by that?

Comment: @Noah Schweber: Nothing deep. Let $z \colon \mathbb{N} \to \mathbb{N}$ be the constant zero function. Then $z$ is computable but $\{z\}$ is not, because of how the definitions work out in each case; as we all know "computable" refers to a different kind of computability in the two settings.

Comment: @CarlMummert My point was really that the OP is probably not familiar with the definition of a set of partial functions being computable, so it's worth giving it or a reference (since otherwise I think they'll just be confused).

Comment: I do think there's a chance, but the example above should show what I mean.

Comment: What do you mean by $x \in (a, b)$ ?  Do you mean something like $a \le x < b$ ?

Comment: Anyway, a partial function with a range of $R$ can be thought of as a total function with a range of $R \cup \{\uparrow\}$ (with $\uparrow$ to represent divergence).  So cardinality won't be $n^n$.